# C: sending GET requests but wireshark doesnt catch anything

Tags: c, sockets, wireshark

I'm new in C and with `wireshark` too. So I'm trying to send http GET request to localhost and simultaneously running `wireshark`. But it seems that I'm doing something wrong because wireshark doesn't show any headers. So here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
 int yes = 1;
 char buffer[1024];

 int newsockfd, portno, number, recv_length, sockfd;
 socklen_t clilen;
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

 if (sockfd < 0) 
    error("ERROR opening socket");
 bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

 serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
 serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
 serv_addr.sin_port = htons(80);

 sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));
 number = send(sockfd, "GET /1/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", strlen("GET /1/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"), 0);

 recv_length = recv(sockfd, buffer, 1024, 0);
 printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

(I'm using some additional variables that I don't use but don't pay attention on that and **/1/** is just my website) This program prints out [this](http://pastebin.com/Bq2Ju25z) I'm running wireshark as root. When I try to catch another websites packets (for example [my friends website](http://shoti.net)) it works ok. And I have another question.Is he response that web server sends me back  just a text like one text file starting with headers and then the body(html)? Sorry if my questions sound silly. Thanks

Comment: `printf("%s\n", buffer);` is dangerous.  Data read via `recv()` is not guaranteed to be NUL-terminated.  It's not safe to treat it as a string.  Also, note that neither `send()` nor `recv()` return `int`.  They both return `ssize_t`.  They are **not** the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't silly. You just are not using any **real** networking while sending packets to the localhost. It's quite possible that wireshark won't catch them on your system. 
Read this: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback

Try to send them to your external IP, or to some other host.

Yes, the response to GET request is just a text of standart format: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPResponseMessageFormat.htm

Comment: Oh yes... I just needed to change my interface to loo (not wlan0) Can you please answer second question?